# How to tell Lineman to copy all files from /dist to a different directory?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-copy, linemanjs

When I run `lineman build` it generates all the minified CSS and JS in the `/dist` directory. I can't figure out how to make it copy those minified files into a different directory( My Public Directory at path - **../lib/app/public**).

My Lineman configuration file looks like this.

```
# Exports an object that defines
#  all of the configuration needed by the projects'
#  depended-on grunt tasks.
#
# You can familiarize yourself with all of Lineman's defaults by checking out the parent file:
# https://github.com/testdouble/lineman/blob/master/config/application.coffee
#

module.exports = require(process.env['LINEMAN_MAIN']).config.extend('application', {
  removeTasks:
    common: [ "webfonts:dev", "images:dev"]
    dist: ["images:dist", "webfonts:dist", "pages:dist"]

  server:
    apiProxy:
      enabled: true
      host: 'localhost'
      port: 4567

  # enableSass: true

  # configure lineman to load additional angular related npm tasks
  loadNpmTasks: [ "grunt-ngmin"]

  # task override configuration
  prependTasks:
    dist: ["ngmin"]         # ngmin should run in dist only

  watch:
    scripts:
      files: ["generated/**"],
      tasks: ['copy:dev']

  copy:
    dev:
      files: [expand: true, cwd: 'generated', src: ['css/**', 'js/**', '!**/spec.js', 
              '!**/*.less*', '!**/*.coffee*', '!**/*.*.map'], dest: '../lib/app/public' ]

  # configuration for grunt-ngmin, this happens _after_ concat once, which is the ngmin ideal :)
  ngmin: {
    js: {
      src: "<%= files.js.concatenated %>",
      dest: "<%= files.js.concatenated %>"
    }
  },
})
```

I know there is a `copy:dist` default task in Lineman but not sure how it works and can't understand it properly from the documentation at http://linemanjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem, with Lineman's help:

- Wrote a custom task, *tasks/dl-dev-copy.js*, to copy the files:

  ```
  module.exports = function(grunt) {
     return grunt.registerTask('dl-dev-copy', 'Copy UI artifacts to wildfly deployment folder', ['copy:dl-dev-copy']);
  };
  ```
- Updated the *application.js* file (the key part is important, I was only able to figure it out after the Lineman folks helped me out):

  ```
  loadNpmTasks: lineman.config.application.loadNpmTasks.concat('grunt-contrib-copy'),
     copy: {
        'dl-dev-copy': {
          files: [{
              expand: true,
              cwd: 'generated/',
              src: ['**'],
              dest: '../../../target/iq/'
          }]
      }
  },
  watch: {
      target: {
          "files": ["app/**/*", "spec/**/*", 'spec-e2e/**/*'],
          "tasks": 'dl-dev-copy'
      }
  },
  appendTasks: {
      common: ["dl-dev-copy"]
  }
  ```
- See below for the output of *lineman run* (it is similar when a file is being watched changes, and we I run *lineman build*):

  ```
  lineman run
  Running "common" task
  ...       
   Running "copy:dl-dev-copy" (copy) task
  Created 6 directories, copied 23 files
  ...
  Running "watch" task
  Waiting...
  ```